# Display pmd reports in gitlab without Code Climate Engines

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, gitlab, integration, pmd

Is it possible to display code quality without Code Climate Engines?
I saw [that](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.html) and I want to avoid docker usage if it possible.
I have maven-pmd-plugin which generates reports but I haven't found way to integrate this.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Did you find a way to integrate PMD on gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

According to the maven pmd plugin [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#format) it should be since there is a [CodeClimateRenderer](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/renderers/CodeClimateRenderer.java) available for PMD.

However after trying it out seems there is some bug preventing it from accepting custom renderers.

```
mvn pmd:pmd -Dformat=net.sourceforge.pmd.renderers.CodeClimateRenderer

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.13.0:pmd (default-cli) on project hello-world: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.13.0:pmd failed: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Can't find PMD custom format net.sourceforge.pmd.renderers.CodeClimateRenderer: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.sourceforge.pmd.renderers.CodeClimateRenderer.<init>(java.util.Properties)
```

Comment: You need to upgrade to 3.14.0